# CONNECT BY or hierarchical queries in RDBMS other than Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, simulation, recursive-query, connect-by

Oracle ships with a very handy feature. You can create hierarchical queries (recursive behaviour) using the following clause:

```
CONNECT BY [NOCYCLE] {condition [AND condition...]} [START WITH condition]
```

As documented here:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm

I'm wondering, are there any other established RDBMS that support an equivalent or similar syntax? Or can recursive behaviour like this be generically simulated using regular SQL?

A good example that I'd like to be able to simulate is this (taken from the Oracle documentation):

```
    SELECT LPAD(' ', 2 * (LEVEL-1)) || last_name org_chart, 
           employee_id, manager_id, job_id
      FROM employees
START WITH job_id = 'AD_VP' 
CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id;
```

Resulting in:

```
ORG_CHART          EMPLOYEE_ID MANAGER_ID JOB_ID
------------------ ----------- ---------- ----------
Kochhar                    101        100 AD_VP
  Greenberg                108        101 FI_MGR
    Faviet                 109        108 FI_ACCOUNT
    Chen                   110        108 FI_ACCOUNT
    Sciarra                111        108 FI_ACCOUNT
    Urman                  112        108 FI_ACCOUNT
    Popp                   113        108 FI_ACCOUNT
  Whalen                   200        101 AD_ASST
  Mavris                   203        101 HR_REP
  Baer                     204        101 PR_REP
  Higgins                  205        101 AC_MGR
    Gietz                  206        205 AC_ACCOUNT
De Haan                    102        100 AD_VP
  Hunold                   103        102 IT_PROG
    Ernst                  104        103 IT_PROG
    Austin                 105        103 IT_PROG
    Pataballa              106        103 IT_PROG
    Lorentz                107        103 IT_PROG
```

The `LEVEL` pseudo column and the indentation achieved with it is not so important to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an article on the developerworks site [Port CONNECT BY to DB2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510rielau/) that does a nice conversion.
Also an interesting article on Explain Extended (Quassnoi's blog) that shows some difference between CONNECT BY and recursive CTE: [Adjacency list vs. nested sets: Oracle](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/28/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-oracle/), being row-based and set-based. He has also a nice article about "SQL Server: are the recursive CTE’s really set-based?". It seems that the "recursive CTE in Oracle is also not set based". I hope this helps with the conversion, recursion in JOOQ and understanding the difference of both implementations of recursion in SQL.

Regards,
JJ.

Comment: That's a very nice resource by developerworks! I like the way it explains all involved keywords and how they would be applied in a recursive CTE. With this resource, I might finally tackle the simulation in http://jooq.org!

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server uses *common table expressions* (WITH statement) to achieve the same (see [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)).

This kind of query can also be used in Oracle (starting with 11g if I'm not mistaken).

The resulting query is more complex:

```
WITH emp(employee_id, manager_id, job_id, last_name, lvl)
AS (
    SELECT e.employee_id, e.manager_id, e.job_id, e.last_name, 1 lvl
    FROM employees e
    WHERE job_id = 'AD_VP'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.employee_id, e.manager_id, e.job_id, e.last_name, r.lvl + 1 lvl
    FROM employees e
    JOIN emp r ON r.employee_id = e.manager_id
)
SELECT LPAD(' ', 2 * (lvl-1)) || last_name org_chart,
    employee_id, manager_id, job_id
FROM emp;
```

Comment: Aah, that's very interesting. I have never thought about the `WITH` clause that way. So in principle, this approach is a bit less powerful (because much more verbose), but more general? Chances are high that this is also supported (in the future) by other RDBMS supporting a `WITH` clause...

Comment: Very very nice. Thanks for the example!

Comment: To complete the picture: recursive CTE is available in Firebird, PostgreSQL, DB2, Teradata and Sybase (and I think H2 as well)

Comment: Hmm @Codo, I was wondering again about these things. In http://www.jooq.org, I support Oracle's `CONNECT BY` syntax already: https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jooq/wiki/Manual/ADVANCED/CONNECTBY. Now, I would like to simulate Oracle's `CONNECT BY` syntax for other RDBMS (in addition to supporting the `WITH` clause itself). Do you think a formal transformation from the simpler `CONNECT BY` clause (with or without `STARTS WITH`) into a CTE can be achieved? That would be an awesome feature for jOOQ...!

Answer (score 2):

A trawl through SO showed the following questions and answers that deal with  hierarchical queries over a variety of databases. The last of these refers to a [MySql resource](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/), that gives a generic SQL approach.

[Building a Table Dependency Graph With A Recursive Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87877/building-a-table-dependency-graph-with-a-recurssive-query)

[Recursive select in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649446/recursive-select-in-sql)

[SQL recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690324/sql-recursive-query)

[Generating Depth based tree from Hierarchical Data in MySQL (no CTEs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/hierarchical-sql-problem)

Comment: Thanks for your hints. That's a nice resource from MySQL