# Sybase ASE data purge batch - design & performance

Tags: batch-processing, sap-ase

I am working on a Sybase ASE (migrating to 15.7) data purge utility to be used by multiple tables/ databases to delete huge amount of unwanted older data.

1. After receiving an input table name, automatically figure out the child tables and delete data. But, I couldn't find an hierarchical query clause like Oracle's "Connect by .. Prior" clause. Is there any other way to implement this?
2. I am deleting data by looping through multiple transaction/ commits in small increments. After the deletes, at what interval, should I do "reorg rebuild"?
3. Do I need to do update statistics? If I have to, what is the criteria that I should consider before doing update statistics?
4. Some tables may be partitioned. Is there anything that I need to consider in partition's perspective?
5. Some of our DB's (i guess index..?) are clustered. I don't have much idea about clustering. Do I need to consider anything in clustering perspective?
6. Send Email at the end of processing. Does built-in email package similar to oracle's UTIL_SMTP?

Comment: Could someone help me with throwing some thoughts on these points?

Comment: For point #1 - Is there a reason that triggers don't automatically delete child records when a parent is deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the points are blank right now, and I will fill them as I get a chance.

1 - Check out [this post on replicating this feature in Sybase ASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401222/connect-by-or-hierarchical-queries-in-rdbms-other-than-oracle).

2 - [My post over on the dba stack covers a lot of the key points on determining when to run a *reorg*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35253/sybase-ase-15-reorg-rebuild-fixes-performance-issues-why-and-how-to-tell-whe)

3 - Since updating statistics can be done more quickly than a reorg(which also updates statistics), it's sometimes used to help improve performance between reorgs.  Deciding when to run them will depend on how quickly performance degrades when you do your purges.  [**sp_sysmon**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00842.1570/html/spsysmon/title.htm) is a valuable tool that can capture metrics to help you make your decision.

4 - Partioned tables shouldn't really impact your purge.  It's another case where it may improve performance for your deletes, as the data may be accessed more quickly than other configurations.

5 - Not really.  In theory your deletes should go a bit faster if your delete is using the clustered index.  Clustered indexes are used to keep the data pages in order, as records are inserted, instead of heaping the inserts.

6 - For Windows based systems, **xp_sendmail** can be used.  For *nix based systems, **xp_cmdshell** can be used to access *sendmail*.  The documentation for those [Extended Stored Procedures is here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1570/html/sprocs/X35170.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs Michael.
These are very very helpful!!