# SQL query for below scenario

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a processDependency table which has thousands of records. Sample records are given below:

```
Proc DepProc
P1   P2
P2   P3
P3   P4
P4   P5
P6   P7
```

So when I run the SQL query I should be able to derive below:

1. P1-P2-P3-P4-P5
2. P6-P7

   Can anyone help me out with a generic SQL.

Comment: tag the dbms being used

Comment: I do not believe that you can have a generic query for hierarchical processing with unlimited depth.  You will need to use RDBMS-specific functionality.

Comment: So if we have a defined depth say for example 12.. Then is it possible?

Comment: is this a database that allows recursive CTEs?  If so that is probably the way to do it.

Comment: If you are OK with 12 self-joins, then Yes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401222/connect-by-or-hierarchical-queries-in-rdbms-other-than-oracle#comment7504770_6401301

Comment: @Hogan it supports CTE.. Could you give a hint or a sample for me to start off..

Comment: it can't be a select statement but a recursive function that can be called inline can produce that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not quite right because it gets all paths from Proc

But you did not make clear which one should be used first.

In any case it should give you an idea.

```
SELECT recurse AS
(
   SELECT Proc AS Start, 
          Proc||COALESCE('-'||DepProc,'') AS PATH, 
          DepProc as Next, 1 as Level
   FROM table

   UNION ALL

   SELECT Start,
          PATH||'-'||t.DepProc,
          t.DepProc as Next,
          Level+1 as Level
   FROM recurse r
   JOIN table t ON r.Next = t.Proc
), recurseWithMax AS
(
   SELECT PATH, Start, MAX(Level) OVER (Partition by Start) as Max, Level
)
SELECT Start, PATH
FROM recurseWithMax
WHERE Level = Max
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hogan, its working after tweaking the CTE query..  Your answer was really very much helpful.